# Constrained minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

$\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{argmin}$ I am trying to solve the prox-mapping:
$$P_x(y) = \argmin_{||z||_2 \leq 1} \left\{ \langle y, z-x \rangle  + \frac{1}{2}||z||^2 - \frac{1}{2}||x||^2 - \langle x, z-x \rangle \right\}$$ which should be equivalent to $$ \argmin_{||z||_2 \leq 1} \left\{ \langle y-x, z \rangle  + \frac{1}{2}||z||^2 \right\}$$ Now without the constraint the problem is straightforward $z = x - y$, but how do I solve this with the constraint? Do I just normalize it i.e. $z = \frac{x - y}{||x-y||_2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding $\frac{1}{2}\|x - y \|^2$ to the minimization problem you obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
z_+ &= \arg\min_{\|z\|\leq 1} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \|x - y\|^2 + \frac{1}{2} \|z\|^2 + \langle z, y - x \rangle \right\} \\
&= \arg\min_{\|z\|\leq 1} \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \|z - (x - y)\|^2 \right\}
\\
&= \mathrm{Proj}_{\mathcal{B}(0; 1)}(x - y),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\mathrm{Proj}_{\mathcal{B}(0; 1)}$ denotes the orthogonal projection onto the unit ball. That projection is given by
$$
z_+ = (x - y) \cdot \min\left\{1, \frac{1}{\|x - y\|}\right\}.
$$